# react native how to show up badge when my app run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been facing a problem for 1 week. My question is I would like to show up new message badge without clicking message room when I run my app  I can show the badge after clicking message room.

[when I run my app. Home page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5eB4.png)

[and then I clicked Message room Now I can see the badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y5Ai.png)

**ChatList component** src/Components/ChatList

```
  const [badgeCount, setBadgeCount] = useState(0);
  const {badgeStateDispatch} = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const unReadMessageQuery = db
    .collection('chats')
    .doc(id)
    .collection('messages')
    .where('user', '==', recipientEmail)
    .where('unread', '==', true);
  const [unReadMessageToBadge] = useCollection(unReadMessageQuery);
  useEffect(() => {
    const badgeMessagesCount = unReadMessageToBadge?.size;
    console.log(badgeMessagesCount);
    setBadgeCount(badgeMessagesCount);
    badgeStateDispatch({type: BADGE_SHOW});
  }, [unReadMessageToBadge]);
```

**reducer**

```
import {BADGE_SHOW, BADGE_RESET} from '../../Constants/actionTypes';

const badgeCount = (state, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case BADGE_SHOW:
      return {...state, badge: (state.badge = true)};
    case BADGE_RESET:
      return {...state, badge: (state.badge = null)};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default badgeCount;
```

**TabNavi** src/Navigator/Tabnavi.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomeStackNavi from './HomeStackNavi';
import ProfileStackNavi from './ProfileStackNavi';
import MessageStackNavi from './MessageStackNavi';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import colors from '../Assets/theme/colors';
import {GlobalContext} from '../Context/GlobalProvider';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabNavi = () => {
  const {
    badgeState: {badge},
  } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: colors.white,
        inactiveTintColor: colors.gray,
        style: {backgroundColor: colors.primary},
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStackNavi}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => <Icon name="home" size={25} color={colors.white} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Messages"
        component={MessageStackNavi}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Entypo name="message" size={25} color={colors.white} />
          ),
          tabBarBadge: badge,
          tabBarBadgeStyle: {
            top: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 9,
            minWidth: 10,
            maxHeight: 10,
            borderRadius: 7,
            fontSize: 10,
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStackNavi}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => <Icon name="user" size={25} color={colors.white} />,
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default TabNavi;
```

**Edit**: This is the parent component of the ChatList.

```
const ChatRoomList = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  if (!user || !user.email) return;
  const {badgeStateDispatch} = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const renderItem = useCallback(({item}) => <ChatList item={item} />, []);
  const keyExtractor = useCallback(item => item.id, []);
  const userChatRef = db
    .collection('chats')
    .where('users', 'array-contains', user.email);
  const [chatsSnapshot] = useCollection(userChatRef);
  const [chatList, setChatList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const chatData = new Array();
    chatsSnapshot?.docs.map(chat => {
      chatData.push({id: chat.id, users: chat.data().users});
    });
    setChatList(chatData);
  }, [chatsSnapshot]);
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      badgeStateDispatch({type: BADGE_RESET});
    }, []),
  );
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={chatList}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        initialNumToRender={7}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ChatRoomList;
```

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your call to check for unread messages is in your ChatList component which is in your second tab. react-navigation only renders that component when you navigate to the second tab so therefore this code is only running when you select that tab.

You must move this call elsewhere, either into a higher order component or out of the React tree altogether, although this would require a bit of reworking as you're relying on hooks.

Comment: I need a doc id (you can see it on the ChatList) I think I can only get it in the ChatList. I was thinking about how to rework this a lot but I couldn't figure it out. could you help me a little bit more?